# jQuery, Ajax fullscreen pop up loading external php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, popup, fullscreen

Apologies in advance for for not having any code samples but I was wondering if you could help me. I want to use jQuery / ajax to load a php page in a full screen pop up. I've done a quick google search but can't find what I am looking for.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which one is your problem, the popup or the ajax part ? Please me more specific. Also, if you need to open a page in a new window, why would you need to load it with ajax ?

Comment: Good point! I don't want to use a plugin, I just want an external php to load in the browser at full screen if that makes sense...

Comment: give it a try `http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/trigger.html`

Answer (score 2):

I have a different solution. You may try it with an `iframe`. Use jQuery to append an iframe script including all relevant codes into some part of your page (like some `div`). This may do it for you including CSS, like;

```
$('<iframe src="your_page.html"/>').appendTo('#your_div');
```

Or you may try something like;

```
$('<iframe src="your_page.html"/>').load(function(){
      alert('the iframe is done loading');
}).appendTo('#your_div');
```

The iframe may be given a CSS styling of;

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: /* some value to display iframe topmost */
```

This will stretch the iframe to full screen. Give it a try.

Or you may make a `<div>` with this style and may use jQuery's `load` function

Comment: The `iframe` might be not even necessary. You could use the `.load` on the div instead and make style the div.

Comment: Yea Rune. I gave iframe as a suggestion sometimes `load` fails and to support CSS

Comment: @Rune I added ur suggestion to my answer

Comment: Honestly, I have never seen `load` failing to fetch a page. Might be because I only load my own pages. It depends if CSS works too. If it's your own page and use classes and IDs it should work.

Comment: @Rune sometimes its like that. If you find my answer helpful, give it an upvote. Thanks.